# PyQT adding data/information to Tabs using a Loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tabs

I am currently stuck trying to figure out how to correct execute a few loops for my program in order to get it to function as I want.

Little background on the program, I have a List of Names, a List of Dictionaries, and a Dictionary. The goal is to compare the List of Dictionaries to the Dictionary to get the correct values. What i mean by this is let's say I have a group of animals (This is the List of Names, Lets call it `setNames`) and each one of these animals (`setNames`) has a different House, Food, Water, and Bed. (This is the list of dictionaries lets call it `setData`). And finally we have the correct value for each one of these dictionaries (`setData`). We'll call this `correct_parameters` .

Since each animals has his own dictionary he has to make sure he has the correct parameter for his own dictionary.

The program does the following.

1. First, it will *"fix"* our List of Dictionaries (`setData`) to allow us to compare it later with our `correct_parameters`
2. Then, once our `setData` is split/striped it will begin a loop process to loop through each animal in our `setNames` list.
3. Finally, once it's finished looping it will create a tab for each individual animal with their parameters that we're incorrect when compared.

Visual Example:

[image: Loop/Tab Example]

To explain the image a bit more, We have our `setNames`, `setData`, and `Correct_parameters` As we see, the `setData` is compared to the `correct_parameters` and anything that is incorrect or does NOT match is printed onto the tab.

Issue:

My issue is that a tab gets created for every single parameter in the Incorrect data:

[image: Tabs]

I'm fairly new to python and i am still trying to figure out how to correct loop this function. any ideas?

Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create a QTabWidget where all the tabs will be held
        self.myTabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()


        # Loop through our animal names
        setNames = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']
        setData = [{'House=15': 'House=15', 'Food=2': 'Food=2', 'Water=4': 'Water=4', 'Bed=6': 'Bed=6'}, {'House=14': 'House=14', 'Food=2': 'Food=2', 'Water=5': 'Water=5', 'Bed=6': 'Bed=6'}, {'House=15': 'House=15', 'Food=8': 'Food=8', 'Water=4': 'Water=4', 'Bed=9': 'Bed=9'}]
        lst = setData
        for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
            o = {}
            for k,v in val.iteritems():
                if '=' in k:
                    k = k.split('=')[0]
                if '=' in v:
                    v = v.split('=')[1]
                    v = v.replace('"','')
                    v = v.strip()
                o[k] = v
            lst[idx] = o
        count = 0
        print lst
        correct_parameter = {'House': '15', 'Food': '12', 'Water': '4', 'Bed': '4'}
        while count < len(setNames):
            for number, item in enumerate(lst,0):
                for tabName in setNames:
                    for param, correct in correct_parameter.items():
                        tabLabel = QtGui.QTextEdit()
                        tabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
                        self.myTabs.addTab(tabWidget, tabName)
                        if item.get(param) != correct:
                            tabLabel.append('{} = {}'.format(param, item.get(param)))
                            # Set the tab widget's layout
                            tabLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
                            tabLayout.addWidget(tabLabel)
                            tabWidget.setLayout(tabLayout)
                        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
                        count += 1


        # Set the main layout
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.myTabs)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # Resize our window and show it
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.show()


import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm rather confused by all of the loops you're doing to populate your tabWidget. You loop over the setNames twice (while count < len(setNames) and for tabName in setNames) which causes a lot of duplication. I think, if you wanted to keep your method, you might want to replace the tabWidget=QtGui.QWidget() with some sort of logic to check if self.myTabs has the current tabName that you're trying to populate and addign to it.

Instead, I think it's easier to consider the problem by looping through the tabs first, and then checking whether the dicts make sense. The following loop should replace your entire while loop:

```
for index, tabName in enumerate(setNames):
    tabWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
    tabLabel = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    nameData = lst[index]
    for k in nameData:
        if nameData[k] != correct_parameter[k]:
            tabLabel.append('{} = {}'.format(k, nameData[k]))
    tabLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    tabLayout.addWidget(tabLabel)
    tabWidget.setLayout(tabLayout)
    self.myTabs.addTab(tabWidget, tabName)
```

Note: Your code lists ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird'] and all of your images swap the order of 'Bird' and 'Dog'.

Comment: Yeah the code list on my visual example is backwards sorry. And i will try it

Comment: This worked great. Thank you I saw my issue with the loops now.